# sql server: how to bulk load csv file with " quota every field?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a pipe delimited csv file, but every field was quoted as following

```
"111"|"test"|"abc"
```

Now I used powershell to remove all " and then save it before the bulk insert. Is it possible just load it without removing "?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need a [format file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337558.aspx) to deal with different column separators `"` then `"|"` then `"|"` ... `"`.

By default, bcp and BULK INSERT deal only with consistent separators

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue a couple years ago and never found a way for the bulk insert to ignore it. After about an hour of researching I decided to just ask our client to re-export the file without the quotes. Fifteen minutes later I was up and running. I'd love to know if there's actually a way to accomplish this, but the bulk-insert feature always seemed rather inflexible so I decided not to burn too much time on it.